# I open up a Design.csproj and a whole solution opens!

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Why?

I expect only the project to open.

The only way that I could accomplish what I wanted to do was to create a new project test.csproj, add design.csproj, save the solution, and then remove test.csproj.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General`, there is a checkbox, labeled "`Always show solution`".

With this option checked, opening a project from within the folder stucture of a solution will still open the whole solution. If you click only the project, I believe the IDE finds the solution by simply traversing the parent directories for the `.sln` file.

The reason I say that is because if you copy the directory containing a single project and paste it somewhere else, then double click it, the project is opened on its own (still inside a solution, but a temporary one, which only exists as an `.suo` file for now (until you save the solution.))

So we are halfway there. Now if you uncheck the option which I mentioned at the start of my post, you will see the project open on its own like so:

[image]

I agree that it should be possible to open a project without a solution (and that it should be easier than it is currently.) I'd go as far as to say that VS should also give you the option to easily make and run programs in a single file without all the hand-holding and creating projects and solutions for you. Perhaps you can, but if so - it's not obvious.

Comment: You're saying that it finds the solution by crawling the directory tree.

Comment: Alright, perhaps not but there are plenty of ways it could find it. That just seemed obvious becuase if you copy the project away from the solution, it no longer finds the solution.

Comment: Actually, I suspect that it _is_ true.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you have "Open most recent solution" in Options?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it was a Solution file (sln), wrongly labeled as a C# Project File (csproj).
If you open the file in a Text Editor you'll see references to other projects, like in a solution file.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Projects are linked to solutions; you cannot open a project without its parent solution.

Otherwise, things like project references wouldn't work.

Comment: I don't see this. I expected the solution file to contain a list of projects that are contained within the solution and that the project could be contained within one or more solutions. When I opened up the sln file, I thought I saw a list of projects. When I opened up the csproj file, I didn't see any reference to the solution. I'm not even sure how the csproj file pointed to the original sln file. What if the project was contained within multiple solutions? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Velika: The solution refers to the project, not the other way around. If you open the `.sln` file in a text editor, you' see lines like: `Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Project1", "Solution1\Project1.csproj", "{6594D860-E1A1-4E24-8A32-D0ED89B04D65}"
EndProject`. These tell the solution which projects to load and from where. Now if you look inside the text of the `.csproj`, you will find no reference to any solution BUT one of the solutions containing that project will be opened when you click it. So you can indeed have the same project in more than one solution.

Comment: YOU said ..." BUT one of the solutions containing that project will be opened when you click it..."
How does it find the colution file? And why would it bother looking for one?

Comment: @RMX: That doesn't explain how VS finds the solution if you open a project inside of it.

Comment: **That's not true**: see my answer below.